# Excel adds @ operator and gives a #NAME? error

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I use a python package (openpyxl) to write Excel spreadsheet with formulas. Most functions work, but Excel adds an @ operator before STDEV.S, which resulted in a #NAME? error when the xlsx file is opened. I think it has something to do with backwards compatibility with STDEV. How do I avoid this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using "=_xlfn.STDEV.S()" seems to work well.